# How to add images into specific folder in Go? Getting error like: `%!(EXTRA *fs.PathError=open /photos: read-only file system)`

Tags: image, file, go, directory

I am trying to put images into a specific folder in Golang. Here is the code below.
This is the function where I create a folder called `photos` in the root directory.

```
func createPhotoFolder(folderName string) {
    err := os.Mkdir(folderName, 777)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating folder: ", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(folderName, " created successfully in the root directory")
}
```

This is the function where I make get request to fetch image and try to put them into a `photos` folder I created earlier.

```
func downloadImages(urls []string) {
    for i, url := range urls {
        resp, err := http.Get(url)
        fmt.Printf("%d inside for loop\n", i)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("error fetching image: ", err)
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        out, err := os.Create("photos")
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Can't put image into folder: ", err)
        }
        defer out.Close()
    }
}
```

This is the error I get when I run the program.

1- If the folder name is written in this way `os.Create("photos")` without forwardslash I get the error message as below.

```
Can't put image into folder: %!(EXTRA *fs.PathError=open photos: is a directory)
```

2- If I write it like `os.Create("/photos")`. I get the error as below.

```
Can't put image into folder: %!(EXTRA *fs.PathError=open /photos: read-only file system)
```

I gave all the permission while creating the `photos` folder in the way of chmod.
I did try using `io.Copy()` but it requires a file parameter which I don't get while creating one using `os.Create()`

How should I create the folder and put the images inside it properly?

Comment: `photos` is the directory you created. You have to create a file under it, like `os.Create("photos/filename")`

Comment: Start by getting your Printf arguments right. Run go vet if you have troubles.

Answer (score 1):

Here, in your code, in os.Create, it should have the complete address of the file to be created along with the name of the file to be created. Like:

```
gopath := "C:/Users/<username>/go/src/photos/" //where photos is the folder you created 
filename := "photo1.jpg"

out, err := os.Create(gopath + filename)
```

Also, as @steven-penny gave in his answer, create a filename from the image name directly from the url. So that you don't have to give the filename for each image you download.

```
out, err := os.create(gopath + filepath.Base(link))
```

And save the image to your system with,

```
out.Readfrom(resp.Body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small program that does what I think you are trying to do:

```
package main

import (
   "net/http"
   "os"
   "path/filepath"
)

func downloadImages(links []string) error {
   tmp := os.TempDir()
   for _, link := range links {
      println(link)
      res, err := http.Get(link)
      if err != nil { return err }
      defer res.Body.Close()
      file, err := os.Create(filepath.Join(tmp, filepath.Base(link)))
      if err != nil { return err }
      defer file.Close()
      file.ReadFrom(res.Body)
   }
   return nil
}

func main() {
   links := []string{
      "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon.png",
      "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico",
   }
   err := downloadImages(links)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
}
```

You'll want to modify it, as you were using a different directory, but it should get you started.

https://golang.org/pkg/os#File.ReadFrom